# Can we always define the expectation of a random variable in terms of a PDF?

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, expected-value

The definition of expectation of a random variable $X$ over a probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma,\operatorname{P})$ in the most general case translates to the below Lebesgue Integral ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value))

$$\operatorname{E} [X]  = \int_\Omega X(\omega)\,d\operatorname{P}(\omega)$$

Where $\operatorname{P}$ is a probability measure defined over the $\Sigma$ (the sigma algebra made up of subsets of the the sample space $\Omega$).
I also see that the $\operatorname{P}$ is also referred to as the distribution in some places.

So my query is as follows:

1. The definition in terms of Lebesgue Integral above translates to the definition:
   $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \int_{R} x f(x)\, dx,$$
   when $f(x)$ is the probability density function of the random variable $X$. So this means that this definition is valid only when we have PDF. So could someone explain why is $\operatorname{P}$ always guaranteed to exists, while the PDF may or may not exist with respect to the continuous random variable case?

Comment: This can be found in any reasonable introductory text on probability theory.

Comment: The [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) is the go-to counterexample: It has a CDF and well-defined moments, but no PDF is possible.

Comment: It's clear at least that PDF may or may not exist, right? For example, discrete random variables clearly do not have PDFs.

Comment: For the discrete case it is clear, with respect to the continuous case is the definition with respect to probability measure always valid?

Comment: yes it is always valid, although it may be infinite.